# Equivalent of boolean or in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I currently search my data for exact matches on one term like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "term_a": "xxxxx"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

However, I want to be able to search on multiple terms and get all documents that match at least one. So in SQL speak `term_a = 'xxxxx' or term_b = 'yyyyy'`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then you can use a `bool` with `should` statements for each `term`:

```
"bool": {
  "should": [
    {
      "term": {
        "term_a": "xxxxx"
      }
    },
    {
      "term": {
        "term_b": "yyyyy"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

If you want to search multiple terms in the **same field** then you can use a [`terms` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html).

Comment: Thanks, that does the trick! If you don't mind, what if I have some additional terms which always have to be present? I.e. `(term_a = 'xxxxx' or term_b = 'yyyyy') and term_c = 'zzzzz' and term_d = 'wwwwww'`?

Comment: You put those in must statements.